# access a dictionary value with dynamic path using in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this piece of code to extract a value from a dictionary object

```
extracted_value = response_content["retrievePolicyBillingSummariesResponse"]["billingSummaries"]["policyBillingSummary"][0]["billingSummary"]["lastPayment"]["status"]
extracted_value = response_content["retrievePolicyBillingSummariesResponse"]["billingSummaries"]["policyBillingSummary"][0]["billingSummary"]["bill"]["dueDate"]
```

These are just two samples but I have a dozen of these with different key/path combinations. 
How can I just call these using a module and do something like this

```
def get_value_from_content (response_content, my_path):
    # how can I use the value in my_path as the key instead of this hard coded path ?
    extracted_value =  response_content["retrievePolicyBillingSummariesResponse"]["billingSummaries"]["policyBillingSummary"][0]["billingSummary"]["lastPayment"]["status"]
    #extracted_value = response_content using my_path is what I would like to do
    return extracted_value

#I get this from a REST API call but skipping the code here and just hard coding to ask the question here
response_content = {u'retrievePolicyBillingSummariesResponse': {u'billingSummaries': {u'policyBillingSummary': [{u'policy': {u'status': u'A', u'policyNumber': u'xyz123', u'writingCompany': u'FBI', u'renewalFlag': u'false', u'convertedRenewalOffer': u'false', u'termExpirationDate': u'2017-06-26', u'lineOfBusiness': u'PC', u'termEffectiveDate': u'2016-06-26', u'riskState': u'CA', u'insureds': {u'namedInsuredSummary': [{u'preferredPostalAddress': {u'streetAddressLine': u'1 disney', u'cityName': u'palo alto', u'zipCode': u'94100', u'isoRegionCode': u'CA'}, u'name': {u'lastName': u'DOE', u'fullName': u'john doe', u'firstName': u'john'}}]}, u'additionalInterests': {u'additionalInterest': [{u'billTo': u'N', u'name': {u'partyType': u'Organization'}}]}, u'type': u'PA', u'statusDescription': u'Active', u'dataSource': u'from_heaven'}, u'billingSummary': {u'paymentRestriction': u'false', u'nextInstallmentAmount': u'0.00', u'bill': {u'installmentNumber': u'1', u'statementDate': u'2016-06-26', u'paymentPlan': u'Direct', u'installmentAmount': u'12.00', u'totalBillAmountDue': u'1.76', u'previousBalance': u'0.00', u'dueDate': u'2016-06-26', u'billingPlan': u'ANN'}, u'lastPayment': {u'status': u'A'}, u'currentBalance': u'16.66', u'payOffAmount': u'15.66', u'isRestrictedToPay': u'false'}}]}}}

my_path = '["retrievePolicyBillingSummariesResponse"]["billingSummaries"]["policyBillingSummary"][0]["billingSummary"]["lastPayment"]["status"]'
get_extracted_item = get_value_from_content(response_content,my_path)

my_path = '["retrievePolicyBillingSummariesResponse"]["billingSummaries"]["policyBillingSummary"][0]["billingSummary"]["bill"]["dueDate"]'
get_extracted_item = get_value_from_content(response_content,my_path)
```

Comment: what about the module you've proposed doesn't work the way you want it to?

Comment: using string path like this is not a good solution since it needs to be parsed or evaluated, when it simply can be changed into list of keys/indexes with iterating through them

Comment: Keep in mind that [Using eval is a bad practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice).

Comment: Thanks, yes I agree, this is a temp solution and I am moving soon towards the answer suggested by Azat or one of the iterations

Answer (score 4):

first of all it will be easier to write small utility function like

```
def extract_from_dictionary(dictionary, *keys_or_indexes):
    value = dictionary
    for key_or_index in keys_or_indexes:
        value = value[key_or_index]
    return value
```

as we can see from your example there is an object called `billingSummary` that appears in required paths, so we can avoid boilerplate with

```
def get_billing_summary(response_content):
    return extract_from_dictionary(
        response_content,
        "retrievePolicyBillingSummariesResponse",
        "billingSummaries",
        "policyBillingSummary",
        0,
        "billingSummary")
```

then we can simply write

```
def get_value_from_content(response_content, *keys):
    billing_summary = get_billing_summary(response_content)
    extracted_value = extract_from_dictionary(billing_summary,
                                              *keys)
    return extracted_value
```

and obtain required objects like

```
last_payment_status = get_value_from_content(response_content,
                                             "lastPayment",
                                             "status")
bill_due_date = get_value_from_content(response_content,
                                       "bill",
                                       "dueDate")
print("last_payment_status:", last_payment_status)
print("bill_due_date:", bill_due_date)
```

gives us

```
last_payment_status: A
bill_due_date: 2016-06-26
```

Comment: this looks great, for the next few days I am going to use eval() and am going to move to this route next week or so. hopefully I can come back with questions for clarification on this any once I soak this in -:)

Comment: Is there a way to see the response content in a beautiful way ? I mean easily readable format .. just like json beautifiers ? I cannot see this in a better format using a json beautifier due to the Lists in between .. not needed programmatically but just like that to try and build utilities for other responses ? (The ones with a different structure )

Comment: @NareshMG: try `from pprint import pprint; pprint(response)`

Comment: and y did I not think of it...had used it in the past a bit but not much and hence forgot...it does the job perfect Sire ! I will now start messing with the magic portion u spilt here and then let u know how it goes...

Comment: one issue which I am seeing is the hard coding of the path , I would like to achieve a method as generic as possible (not sure to what extent it can be achieved)...and then say I just give the names of the key and parent, exactly as you have done..example..."bill", "dueDate" OR "lastPayment","status" OR "billingSummary","paymentRestriction"

Answer (score 2):

What about using an iterative solution, as follows:

```
response_content = {u'retrievePolicyBillingSummariesResponse': {u'billingSummaries': {u'policyBillingSummary': [{u'policy': {u'status': u'A', u'policyNumber': u'xyz123', u'writingCompany': u'FBI', u'renewalFlag': u'false', u'convertedRenewalOffer': u'false', u'termExpirationDate': u'2017-06-26', u'lineOfBusiness': u'PC', u'termEffectiveDate': u'2016-06-26', u'riskState': u'CA', u'insureds': {u'namedInsuredSummary': [{u'preferredPostalAddress': {u'streetAddressLine': u'1 disney', u'cityName': u'palo alto', u'zipCode': u'94100', u'isoRegionCode': u'CA'}, u'name': {u'lastName': u'DOE', u'fullName': u'john doe', u'firstName': u'john'}}]}, u'additionalInterests': {u'additionalInterest': [{u'billTo': u'N', u'name': {u'partyType': u'Organization'}}]}, u'type': u'PA', u'statusDescription': u'Active', u'dataSource': u'from_heaven'}, u'billingSummary': {u'paymentRestriction': u'false', u'nextInstallmentAmount': u'0.00', u'bill': {u'installmentNumber': u'1', u'statementDate': u'2016-06-26', u'paymentPlan': u'Direct', u'installmentAmount': u'12.00', u'totalBillAmountDue': u'1.76', u'previousBalance': u'0.00', u'dueDate': u'2016-06-26', u'billingPlan': u'ANN'}, u'lastPayment': {u'status': u'A'}, u'currentBalance': u'16.66', u'payOffAmount': u'15.66', u'isRestrictedToPay': u'false'}}]}}}

my_path = [
    "retrievePolicyBillingSummariesResponse",
    "billingSummaries",
    "policyBillingSummary",
    0,
    "billingSummary",
    "lastPayment",
    "status"
]

def get_value_from_content(extraction, my_path):
    for el in my_path:
        if isinstance(extraction, dict):
            extraction = extraction.get(el, extraction)
        else:
            extraction = extraction[el]
    return extraction

extraction = get_value_from_content(response_content, my_path)
print(extraction)
```

The function `get_value_from_content` can even be shorter than before, i.e.

```
def get_value_from_content(extraction, my_path):
    for el in my_path:
        extraction = extraction[el]
    return extraction
```

This last version of `get_value_from_content` is nonetheless more prone to throw exceptions if one has, e.g. misread the chaining of path components. It thus remains to be determined whether the string object `my_path` is human- or machine-made.

Which, in the two cases, returns `"A"`. ***Tested*** in Python 2 and 3. Note also that I favor an iterative solution over a recursive one since [the former is usually faster than the latter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278327/danger-of-recursive-functions). Between [20% and 40% faster in the present case](http://ideone.com/lcOw1S).

That being said, **this does not address the question**, since `my_path` is originally not a list object, but a string object. **To adress the question**, one would first convert this string into a list of keys/indexes, and then process it as mentioned above. Or, as @Minji does, one may want to use the python built-in function [`eval`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/eval). Even if using this function is said to be [a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice), I wonder to what extent the use of `eval` cannot be described in this situation as the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

What about a recursive function?

```
def get_value(response, index):
    if len(index) > 1:
        return get_value(response[index[0]], index[1:])
    else:
        return response[index[0]]

index = ["retrievePolicyBillingSummariesResponse", "billingSummaries", "policyBillingSummary", 0, "billingSummary", "lastPayment", "status"]

get_value(response_content, index)
```

Answer (score -1):

`eval()` interprets a string as code

```
def get_value_from_content (response_content, my_path):
    # string is arguments name
    item = "response_content" + my_path
    return eval(item)
```

Comment: not able to upvote for two answers...but thanks for the answer !